# Converting multiple properties and/or classes created from XML into auto properties in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Paste special as JSON creates a nice compact class with auto properties. Paste special as XML for the same data creates classes using the normal property approach even though all that is in the property is a get/set. So you end up with a private variable and half a dozen lines for each variables with a default get/set.

1. Is there a way to get paste XML to class to create auto properties instead?
2. Is there a way (not just for XML created classes) to convert multiple private variables to auto properties because all I can seem to do is one at a time. Without using external tools like ReSharper.

The time taken to auto convert each field, one at a time, is slower than doing a bit of regex on the code.

I'm on VS2017.
Thanks.

Comment: The long path may be to follow those guide line  on "[How to add a custom Paste Special command to the VS Editor menu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsx/2016/04/21/how-to-add-a-custom-paste-special-command-to-the-vs-editor-menu/)" with a twist. We [convert](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJson.htm) the XML from the clipboard to a json an call the Json Special past. Then we distribute the VSIX Project for the community. Once done it's a simple click

Comment: I was on my way to do it but is was simplier to record 4 click, and play it as a macro.

Answer (score 2):

If JSON does provide you with the right format just convert your [xml to json](https://codebeautify.org/xmltojson) and than special paste your JSON.

Comment: Thanks, I can do that, I can also search/replace with regex (just about), I just thought there must be a way to configure XML to class to use auto properties, maybe in a config/setting somewhere. 

I guess it's either the underlying structure of XML is stopping this or more likely this whole paste/special facility was an afterthought and XML was added first before auto-properties and nobody at MS has bothered to update since EF is taking over?

Hence my other question on whether there's a way of creating an auto-property for multiple fields rather than one at a time

Answer (score -3):

Pretty simple...

As an example get some xml e.g from link https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml (as you have not provided some sample xml)

Go to Visual Studio >> Edit >> Paste Special >> Paste XML as Classes

[image: Paste Special]

This will generate class and its properties for you.

Comment: This is not the question. He knows about the special paste:Paste special as XML for the same data creates classes using the normal property approach even though all that is in the property is a get/set. So you end up with a private variable and half a dozen lines for each variables with a default get/set.

Is there a way to get paste XML to class to create auto properties instead?